# Do movie producers get pre-emptive waivers/insurance prior to releasing a movie? [Spoiler]

Tags: product-liability

Warning this post contains a spoiler!

In [How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Train_Your_Dragon:_The_Hidden_World), at the end of the movie:

> they show Hiccup and Astrid tossing their children around from dragon to dragon as they do daredevil stunts in the sky.

This is similar to many incidents that occur when kids see things on TV and try to replicate them in real life. [This article](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1993-10-14-ca-45776-story.html) is an example of numerous such incidents over the years. As a result many ads now have the disclaimer "Do not try this at home" etc...

But in movies, there is no such disclaimer when a stunt like that occurs? Is it at the end of the credits where people never read?
Or does someone in Hollywood look at a scene in the movie pre-air and decide "oop, this might be a potential litigation" and prompt a waiver of some sorts that indemnifies them against potential lawsuits?